# Query from database does not return in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

My rails app has a User model and a Role model. Each User belongs to one role and each role has many users. There three methods defined in the user model to check the role of that user `def admin?`, `def user?`, and `def expert?`.

The User class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader

  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_presence_of   :avatar
  validates_integrity_of  :avatar
  validates_processing_of :avatar

  before_save :assign_role
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  belongs_to :role
  has_many :items
  belongs_to :organization
  has_many :expertkeywordmodels
  has_many :keywords, through: :expertkeywordmodels

  def assign_role
    self.role = Role.find_by name: "Admin" if self.role.nil?
  end

  def self.with_role(role)
     my_role = Role.find_by_name(role)
     where(:role => my_role)
  end

  def admin?
    self.role.name == "Admin"
  end

  def user?
    self.role.name == "User"
  end

  def expert?
    self.role.name == "Expert"
  end

end
```

The Role class:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end
```

I am trying to create a `collection_select` only with users that have `expert` role. Something like:

```
<%= collection_select(:keyword, :user_ids, User.where('expert?'), :id, :name, {prompt: true}, {:multiple => true}) %>
```

But it does not recognize `expert?` as a method. I was wondering if anyone knows how can I perform this query.
I am sorry if this is a naive question as I am new to rails.

Thanks,
Amir

Comment: what happens when you try User.where(role: {name: "expert"})

Comment: If you fire up `rails c` and try this `User.last.expert?` what do you get?

Comment: `User.last.expert?` returns false and `User.last.admin?` returns true which means it is correct. @KarimTarek

Comment: @ruby_newbie it returns there is no such column `role.name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`User.where('expert?')` doesn't really makes sense for the database, because it would translate to SQL like:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE expert?;
```

And obviously `expert?` isn't a valid SQL expression. `expert?` is only available in the context of your code.

Instead you need to write that logic in a way that translates to valid SQL and makes sense in the context of your database schema. My guess is that the following might work:

```
User.joins(:role).where(roles: { name: 'Expert'})
```

You might want to define a `scope` in your `User` model, like this:

```
scope :experts, -> { joins(:role).where(roles: { name: 'Expert'}) }
```

Than `User.experts` would return all users that have the expert role.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked like a charm and definitely I need to improve my SQL knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Not for nothing, but you have three methods in your user model that all set the same field, just differently.

```
def role(role_type)
  self.role.name = role_type
end
```

To get your desired require to work properly - you can either write a scope or a method.

```
def get_roles(role_type)
   User.role.name = role_type
end
```

Rail Guides are always extremely helpful.  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments